# Failing to load model in keras after saving on a different machine (shape mismatch)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When trying to load a model that has been saved on a different computer, tensorflow reports a shape error (even though on the computer that the model was saved on, it loads without a problem):

```
InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be at least rank 3 but is rank 2 for '{{node BiasAdd}} = BiasAdd[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW"](add, bias)' with input shapes: [?,512], [512].
```

Answer (score 0):

After quite some clueless debugging, it turned out I had `"image_data_format": "channels_first"` set in `%USERPROFILE%/.keras/keras.json` and the model was saved with `"channels_last"` instead.